# Remove characters in all text files in a directory using sed

Tags: for-loop, sed

I have a lot of text files that are email templates. Many of them, for some reason, have the following line:

```
Best Regards,œ
```

That strange character at the end is what I am interested in removing from all of these files with a single command.

I tried:

```
for f in *
do 
  sed 's/"Best Regards,œ"/"Best Regards,"/g' $f | tee $f.t && mv $f.t $f
done
```

This ran through the process but did not actually remove the 'œ' character.

Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly so I can remove this character and maybe other non-alphanumeric characters using regex [:alnum:], perhaps.

I fixed the issue with removing the unwanted character with:

```
for f in * 
do 
  sed 's/Best\ Regards\,\œ/Best\ Regards\,/g' $f | tee $f.t && mv $f.t $f   
done
```

However, this still does not remove all of the non-alphanumeric characters from each line of each file. The other things I have tried either do not execute or remove the entire line.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: How did you add the character to the command line?

Comment: find . -type f -name '*.txt' probably would have done the same.

Comment: What do you mean by `all of the non-alphanumeric characters`? Suppose if you have a `§` in your file, do you wish to remove that too? or is that you have  more than one `œ` in each of the file?

Comment: § is not a character in these files. That raises a good point if there was a legal document or something citing law. I am referring to characters such as  'œ', which are not on my USA English keyboard. In this case, I need ; , / \ . [ ] { } | - = + ( ) * & ^ % $ # @ ! ~ ` ? > < " ' and :.

Comment: @technerdius, Technically, `œ` *is* part of the alphanumeric set. The [section sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign), (along with its friend the [pilcrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow)) is not. When writing your filter, it is probably easier to "permit what you want" rather than "remove what you don't want".  `sed -e 's/[^[:print:]]//g'` might be a useful experiment.

Comment: @ghotib that was very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ① you don't want to have to worry about Unicode, UTF-anything, LANG, etc, and ② you are confident that lines that start with the words "Best Regards," and ONLY those lines are the ones you want to affect, you can simply do this:

```
sed -i .bak '/^Best Regards,.*/s//Best Regards,/' *
```

Note that this processes *all files in the current directory*. If you want to do this in subdirectories, you could use find, with all its goodness. For example:

```
find /path/to/start/ -exec \
  sed -i .bak '/^Best Regards,.*/s//Best Regards,/' {} \;
```

or if your shell is bash, you could use globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*; do
  sed -i .bak '/^Best Regards,.*/s//Best Regards,/' "$f"
done
```

Rather than using `tee` and `mv`, these solutions use sed's built-in "in-place" option, and creates a .bak file as a result. Consult the documentation for your implementation of `sed` to learn more about how to use the `-i` option -- it works a little differently with different `sed`s.

This approach eliminates the need to search for that character in particular, so you won't need to worry about how it's being represented.  Beware though, it will also eliminate any other text that follows the search string on the same line.

Comment: Why a loop over the glob? We can simply pass the results of the glob to sed as I've shown..

Comment: You are right. 'sed -i .bak '/^Best Regards,.*/s//Best Regards,/' *' is easier. I guess I thought it would not work without a loop for some reason.

Comment: @hek2mgl - excellent point, clarified. I should really stop stackoverflowing before I've metabolized my first coffee of the day. :-P

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the loop. You can pass the results of the glob expression directly to sed and use the `-i` option for *in place* editing of files:

```
sed -i.bak 's/Best Regards,œ/Best Regards,/' *
```

`-i.bak` changes the input file *in place* and creates a backup file with the extension `.bak`.

Some implementations of `sed`, for example GNU `sed` even support `-i` without an argument other allow an empty string as argument for `-i`. In that case `sed` will not keep any backup files and simply change the original file.

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/Best Regards,œ/Best Regards,/' *
# OR (BSD, MacOS)
sed -i '' 's/Best Regards,œ/Best Regards,/' *
```

Comment: FYI, while GNU sed allows `-i` to be specified without an optarg, BSD sed allows you to specify an empty optarg (i.e. with a pair of single quotes), which has the same effect of making no backup.

Comment: @ghoti Oh, nice! Never knew that.

Comment: Mine is GNU, but that is great to know. Thank you @ghoti